# Unable to connect with HTTP proxy

Tags: go

**go version: go1.13.5 linux/amd64**

I am using "x/net/proxy" to connect with the "http_proxy".

I have referred following proxy page:
https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/proxy

To get proxy information I have set environment variable "all_proxy" to the the desired proxy "http://192.130.0.10:3200", and performed the tcp connection, but following error is raised:

**[Network Error : socks connect tcp 192.130.0.10:3200->mx.eu1.mico.io:8883: read tcp 172.17.0.2:48118->192.130.0.10:3200: read: connection reset by peer]**

I have looked "x/net/proxy", It seems "http_proxy" support is not available instead of "SOCKS5" proxy is supported. I have similar implementation for "http_proxy", but unfortunately it does not worked.

**I have created a sample code (with port 1883) which is working for the non proxy environment, Please suggest how I can enable "http_proxy" or "https_proxy" support?**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"

    "golang.org/x/net/proxy"
)

//The host address which we want to connect with the proxy
var host = "google.com:80"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Inside main...")

    //Setting the proxy before starting the application
    if os.Getenv("http_proxy") == "" {
        os.Setenv("http_proxy", "http://192.130.0.10:3200")
    }
    os.Setenv("all_proxy", os.Getenv("http_proxy"))

    if os.Getenv("all_proxy") != os.Getenv("http_proxy") {
        fmt.Println("Environment variables are not matching...")
        return
    }

    fmt.Println("System proxy is:", os.Getenv("all_proxy"))

    proxyDialer := proxy.FromEnvironment()

    fmt.Println("Connecting to...", host)

    conn, err := proxyDialer.Dial("tcp", host)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Unable to dial...", err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println("Connected...", conn)
}
```

---

```
Output:
Inside main...
System proxy is: http://192.130.0.10:3200
Connecting to... google.com:80
Unable to dial... dial tcp 172.217.23.174:80: connect: connection timed out
```

Comment: You don't have to do anything special in most cases. [The standard library respects http_proxy by default](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#DefaultTransport).

Answer (score 0):

What's your purpose? 
If you need to use an http-proxy server for http requests, you can just configure your http-client without another package usage:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "net/url"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    proxyUrl, err := url.Parse("http://192.130.0.10:3200")
    if err != nil {
        // TODO handle me
        panic(err)
    }

    cl := http.Client{
        Transport: &http.Transport{
            Proxy: http.ProxyURL(proxyUrl),
        },
        Timeout: 3000 * time.Millisecond,
    }

    resp, err := cl.Get("http://google.com")
    if err != nil {
        // TODO handle me
        panic(err)
    }

    // TODO work with the response
    fmt.Println(resp)
}
```

Comment: Hi Igor, thanks for your answer...

Following is my use case:
`- I am using "paho.mqtt.golang" to connect to various cloud, its a TCP base approach where I am using 1883 and 8883 port to communicate further, the mqtt library is using "golang.org/x/net/proxy" to handle proxy but support is only for the "SOCKS5" proxy.

- I am under corporate proxy which is of http, so can not use SOCKS for the same( hence thought to implement http proxy for the same).

- I will create a connection and keep it open, so that later I can use use it as soon as I will get a request from the client.`

Comment: @IAMSKU: A HTTP proxy is not a generic TCP proxy like SOCKS.  While one might maybe try to tunnel to arbitrary ports using CONNECT request the is commonly restricted to only a few ports. In other words: you likely would not be able to use a HTTP proxy for your non-HTTP protocol anyway.